# elasticsearch 1.1.1 JDBC river plugin

Tags: stored-procedures, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

```
{
  "type" : "jdbc",
  "jdbc" :{
    "strategy" : "oneshot",
    "index" : "exec_jdbc_index",
    "type" : "exec_jdbc_type",
    "driver" : "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
    "url" : "jdbc:sqlserver://host:1433;databaseName=MyDB",
    "user" : "user",
    "password" : "password",
    "sql":  "Exec MyProcName",        
    "callable" : true,            
    "fetchsize" : 1000        
   }
}
```

and I am getting the following exception:

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: A result set was generated for update.
```

Please advice, how to call stored proc from JDBC River Plugin. Simple Select is working fine.

Sure, here is the trace: [ERROR][org.xbib.elasticsearch.river.jdbc.strategy.simple.SimpleRiverFlow] com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: A result set was generated for update.
java.io.IOException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: A result set was generated for update.
    at org.xbib.elasticsearch.river.jdbc.strategy.simple.SimpleRiverSource.fetch(SimpleRiverSource.java:231)
    at org.xbib.elasticsearch.river.jdbc.strategy.simple.SimpleRiverFlow.move(SimpleRiverFlow.java:129)
    at org.xbib.elasticsearch.river.jdbc.strategy.simple.SimpleRiverFlow.run(SimpleRiverFlow.java:88)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: A result set was generated for update.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:171)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:797)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:676)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:4575)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1400)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:179)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:154)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerStatement.java:633)
    at org.xbib.elasticsearch.river.jdbc.strategy.simple.SimpleRiverSource.executeUpdate(SimpleRiverSource.java:522)
    at org.xbib.elasticsearch.river.jdbc.strategy.simple.SimpleRiverSource.execute(SimpleRiverSource.java:260)
    at org.xbib.elasticsearch.river.jdbc.strategy.simple.SimpleRiverSource.fetch(SimpleRiverSource.java:227)
    ... 3 more

Answer (score 0):

Are you returning any "_id" from stored proc result set ? I believe _id is required in indexing to keep it unique.Try returning _id as part of result set.If it doesn't help,could you please add some more part of stack trace to understand the actual root cause.

Comment: Sure, here is the trace

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally found out where the problem was. Callable statements were not parsed as callable.

I modified `SimpleRiverSource` java class, method fetch(), looks like even the callable statement were going to `execute()` or `executeWithParameter(command);`. I made a simple change to call 
`executeCallable(command);`
in there directly and it started to work.